# Merge array values in a single array by removing duplicates and null values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
             [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1234
                    [name] => John
                )

             [1] => Array
                (

                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1234
                    [name] => John
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5678
                    [name] => Sally
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1234
                    [name] => Duke
                )
)
```

My resulting array should be the following (basically merging and getting rid of duplicates and removing null values):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [id] => 1234
           [name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           [id] => 5678
           [name] => Sally
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
           [id] => 1234
           [name] => Duke
        )
)
```

Is there an easy way to do this using PHP's array functions?

EDIT: So far I have this:

```
$result = array();
      foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
          $result = array_merge($result, $value);
        }
      }
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Have you looked or thought about any way to do this?

Comment: added a possible solution

Comment: You have 3 dimensional arrays always?

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge` to merge the arrays. Then use `array_unique` to remove duplicates. Finally, to remove null keys, use a loop.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_null($value) || $value == '')
        unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Documentation on these methods can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: How do I remove duplicates in an array with associative key value pairs?

Comment: Duplicate keys or duplicate keys with duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

1. Flatten your unnecessarily depth array structure by unpacking the subarrays into a merge call.
2. Filter out the empty subarrays with `array_filter()`.
3. Remove the duplicate subarrays with `array_unique()`. (`SORT_REGULAR` prevents "Warning: Array to string conversion")

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/B8BOl))

```
var_export(
    array_unique(
        array_filter(
            array_merge(...$array)
        ),
        SORT_REGULAR
    )
);
```

4. Optionally, call `array_values()` on the resultant array to re-index it (remove the old keys).